# ANVIZ T5 Pro Card Reader connect to C# Windows Project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, device, biometrics

I Have a ANVIZ T5 Pro Proximity reader, but I don't have a Proper SDK.
So I found the DLL files in installed location "CrossChex" application.

Now I have DLL files called,

1. ACE.DLL
2. AvzScanner.DLL
3. FaceSdk_V1.0.ocx
4. FaceSdk_V2.0.ocx
5. Facial.DLL

When I add a .dll file as a reference in C# application it shows an error :

> A reference to the "....dll" could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

when I add the DLL it's getting below error massage.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because compiled version of DLL. 
You have to import native wrote dll like this:

```
[DllImport("tc400.dll")]
    public static extern int methodName();
```

It will be method of class where you declare it.
But you have to know method names to include it and use. 
Good luck